# d3.js: Horizontally center a <g> element with an unknown size within it's parent <svg> element

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, decision-tree

I'm creating a decision tree in d3.js and I'm having trouble centering it's g element within the parent svg element. The g element's width is unknown.

How would I center the g element horizontally?

If you need code samples, let me know and I'll post. Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
              .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0,40)")
                .attr("id", "decision-tree");
var box = d3.select("#decision-tree").getBBox();
```

This results in an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: d3.select(...).getBBox is not a function

I can't seem to find any examples of using getBBox with d3.js through google. Can you link some examples if you know of any?

Comment: You need to know the width. You can use `.getBBox()` on the DOM element to get its size.

Comment: To get the width you should do `var box = d3.select("#decision-tree").node().getBoundingClientRect().width;` You can get `width` , `height` , `x` and `y`.

Comment: Well [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929) is the first result when I google for "d3 getbbox". Also, you use it on the DOM node, not the D3 selection, like I've said.

Comment: Thanks @DavidDomain, that solved the issue for me. Your input, Lars, was great as well, helped me understand this issue a ton more.

Comment: @BrentMorrow - You should actually use the `getBBox()` like Lars Kotthoff mentioned, sorry. `getBoundingClientRect()` may give you unexpected results when using transformations.

Comment: Ok, will do. Both solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can append a `center` element before the svg element to bring the whole svg horizontally in the center. But inserting a `center` element after `svg` and before `g` won't work. You'll have to use this workaround or use variables to translate the `g` element. See the following code for an example:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("center")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
svg.append("g")
   .append("text")
   .text("Blah Blah Blah")
```

Note that the following won't position the `text` in the center of `g`:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
svg.append("center")
   .append("g")
   .append("text")
   .text("Blah Blah Blah")
```